# Cassandra data modeling for calculation

Tags: cassandra, nosql, cassandra-3.0, spring-data-cassandra

I have `customer_info` table in cassandra. It will have the following columns.

1. UUID is the primary key.
2. customer_id
3. amount
4. other fields ...

**100$ transaction limit for each customer during a 365 days**.

I have following 2 options

1. Select all records of particular **`customer_id`** from customer table. Do calculation in memory at application code; if transaction limit is not crossing 100$ then do the insert or update in the customer_info table.
2. Maintain a new table **`customer_limit`** which will consist of `customer_id` and `limit` fields. Before CRUD operation on `customer_info`, I will query on `customer_limit` table to know the limit and based on the limit do the CRUD operation on `customer_info` table.

In terms of maintenance and faster read/write, which option is best suited ?

Comment: First: how you'd query for *customer_id* if your primary key is UUID only?

Comment: I forgot to mention about Index on "customer_id"

Answer (score 1):

I would use 2 tables for this purpose.

`table-2` would be a counter table with `limit` as the counter value. You should always query this `table-2` before inserting into customer_info table.

Refer [Counters](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useCountersConcept.html) here. They are easy to make concurrent increments avoiding read before write in application source code.

Also please read about Partion and Clustering key concepts. Your choice of keys for `customer_info` is not very good.

Answer (score 1):

I think you must keep the details of each transaction, because you need a "moving" window of fixed aperture (365 days) that "advances" at each transaction.

You could create a `transactions` table with the following primary key fields pair:

```
(customer_id, transaction_date)
```

By clustering in `DESC` order this table (by date of course) then you can always query for the last 365 days, efficiently, everyday.